# How to release back RDS CAL lic to license server

Tags: rds, cal

Is there any way to retake back license from RDS host? For example, my session host A connect to license server which has 20 CALs. After 5 RDP session to host A, license server show that 15 lic available. But I want session host A to release back that 5 lic count to license server because other session hosts might need it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about it. The 20 CALs on your licensing server will allow up to 20 concurrent RDP sessions across all session hosts that are configured to use that license server for licensing. The process of releasing and reassigning is automatic.